# How can I register IAuthenticationManager in Global.asax with StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I want register IAuthenticationManager  in Application_Start() with this code:

```
//
 x.For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

When I run my mvc5 project I get this error

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the overload for Use that you are invoking here is attempting to resolve immediately and there is no current HttpContext during App Start.  Try using the overload for Use that has a Func parameter to be used for construction.

```
x.For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use(ctx => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

Comment: Thanks,it's worked...Can you more explain about this why when I use construction it's worked?

Comment: By using the Func overload, you are deferring execution until the time when the dependency needs to be resolved by the container. The first overload is attempting to resolve the instance immediately which is during the application startup, where there isn't an HttpContext. Simply, it's the difference between giving the container an instance upfront and telling it to resolve by sending back that instance vs. telling the container how to create an instance when asked.